# Lambda API result as a condition to create AWS resource in Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Is it possible within AWS Cloud formation to Conditionally create AWS resources based on Lambda APi response.

for e.g
Let's say, we have a requirement to execute Lambda API with some parameter based on which validations will be done and there will be response like `{"valid": false|true}` .
Based on this response field, we should either create AWS resource like EC2 or return failure to the user with some message.

I could not find anything much in Cloud Formation documentation related to this and conditional expression in the documents referenced the parameters passed to the CFT as inputs.

Any suggestions or approach to tackle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) or your own cloudformation template [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) to achieve what you want.